# SQL - Count occurences duplicated rows and get these values to set an another columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello to the community,

I have a small problem with my SQL query, I would like to count the duplicated rows first and then use this value to calculate another value and assign it to a column.

My subquery is ok and return the right number of occurrences.

After count, I use an Alias named "DailyPointing" to compute "TheoreticalHoursByMonth = TheoreticalHoursByMonth divide by number of occurences"

Currently, the error message is that it does not recognize "DailyPointing".

`Error 1054 - Unkown column 'DailyPointing' IN/ALL/ANY subquery"`

Here is my request:

```
UPDATE company_parc
SET 
    TheoreticalHoursByMonth = TheoreticalHoursByMonth / DailyPointing in (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) as DailyPointing
    FROM
        company_parc
        GROUP BY MchCode , PointingDate
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   );
```

Thank for your help !

Comment: First thing to test is does your sub query work/return what your expecting before applying the outer query?  I dont know mysql syntax, but maybe the way you formatting the update is off?  Or is there a coulumn in your company_parc table already called DailyPointing?  Could be confused?  Do you have exact error?

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax. Use subquery as one more row source (UPDATE table JOIN (subquery) AS sq) with proper joining condition.

Comment: Your query has multiple syntax issues. Please explain what you want to achieve, and also please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I added more details to explain what I want